# Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (Using password: NO), when I am using a password

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

This is my code, on a remote server:

```
$username = 'myuser';
$password = 'password';
mysql_connect('localhost', $username, $password) or die ('blah blah blah');
```

And **occasionally**, it gives me this error:

> Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

This error persists for around **6 minutes**, then fades away

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

P.S.: Please don't worry about me using `mysql_*`. I also use mysqli, and the problem also occurs. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "occasionally" and "fades away"?

Comment: @BotskoNet Well, like, the problem comes around once every day, stays for six minutes, then goes away.

Comment: @BotskoNet Though very occasionally it persists for around 40 minutes.

Comment: That's bizarre. Is the MySQL server even responsive during that "downtime"? I've never seen it reject connections inconsistently. Is there only a single MySQL install, locally, and there's no chance the PHP script could begin using different credentials? No one is loading another script/setting different credentials?

Comment: I'd suggest to implement a simple log to find out what is being called and making sure your password variable is being filled. also did you have a look into the mysql/php log? perhaps there is a problem in the configuration?

Comment: @BotskoNet No, don't think so. Couldn't even access PhpMyAdmin through the cPanel on my website during that time.

Comment: That seems like a strong indication of the problem. If you can't even access PMA/Cpanel, there's an issue with the server not responding at all.

Comment: Could it be your web host - some sort of DDOS protection. Have you fiddled with any settings like that recently?

Comment: @BotskoNet No, I can access cPanel & anything not including the mysql connection file, but once it's database related, it stuffs up.

Comment: @BotskoNet Yep, and now, it's working again. Voila.

Comment: Understood, but I think the fact that when this happens, nothing else seems capable of connecting to the db is an indication that the database server is somehow unavailable. Maybe it's crashing, maybe it's consuming resources due to a bad query, maybe it's being attacked, there are a billion causes. Check your error logs etc to find out where MySQL is going...

Comment: @BotskoNet Is it possible to access the logs via cPanel, or the backend files?

Comment: @think123 Maybe you should report this to your hosting company ...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I have, they just haven't helped me solve the problem yet.

Comment: I'm not experienced much with cpanel... haven't used it in half a decade. I doubt you can, and agree that this is an issue for your hosting provider to resolve.

Comment: What version of MySQL server?

Comment: @sectus Server version: 5.5.30-log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, the error you are receiving is

> Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

and not

> blah blah blah

as defined in the `die ('blah blah blah');` segment; the error is not because of your connection to MySQL server.

This is most probably because the user **myuser** does not have `PRIVILEGES` to perform the task you are asking it to do(may be `DELETE`, may be `UPDATE` or may even be `SELECT`)

Comment: So if the user lacks privileges, the function tell you you aren't using a password even though you are?  That does not seem logical!